# How to run Tabler in production

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, jekyll

On my local machine I have been developing on a [tabler](https://github.com/tabler/tabler) clone. To run it, I do as the repo suggests and run `npm run serve`. This brings up nice dev tools like auto-compiling scss and livereloading after changes. Further, `npm run dist` creates a `/dist` folder with my sites contents. However, I want to run this on an EC2 instance, but am unsure how to run for a production environment. How would I do this?

A direct Tabler clone is live [here](http://13.57.240.29:5000/) on my server. As you can see it takes too long to serve up the basic index page. This is the issue I am trying to solve by running in production

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My solution was to wrap the code in `/dist` with a new node/express program. I set up a basic express app under `/prod`. In `app.js` I have the following code.

```
const dist = path.join(__dirname, '/public/');
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(dist, '/index.html'));
});
```

For production, first I call `npm run dist`

Then I call `npm run prod` which does the following: `"prod": "del ./prod/public && move-cli --mkdirp ./dist/ ./prod/public"`

Now the server is runnable using `node prod/bin/www`